# How can I assign a placeholder datatype to custom classes dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics

So I'm noticing that I am using a lot of the same code over and over and over again... So I want to make a universal class where possible, so I don't have the same function redefined in multiple places...

As an example I wanted to try and do this with a `SortedDictionary`. To do this, I need to be able to assign the data types of the dictionary when I create the custom `SortedDictionary`.

Is this possible? Something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Controller.Framework
{
   class CSortedDictionary
   {
      private SortedDictionary<CustomDataType, CustomDataType> m_dictionary;
   }
}

// Create custom dictionary...
CSortedDictionary<int, List<string>> custom_dictionary
    = new CSortedDictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just inherit your class from SortedDictionary with specific generic parameters.

```
public class CSortedDictionary : SortedDictionary<int, List<string>>
{
}
```

And use `CSortedDictionary` - it will have integer keys and values of `List<string>` type:

```
CSortedDictionary custom_dictionary = new CSortedDictionary();
custom_dictionary.Add(42, new List<string>());
custom_dictionary[42].Add("Foo");
```

Comment: Yes, but how would I assign the CustomDataType's to a specific data type? Say int as the key and List<string> as the value?

Comment: @Ricky `CSortedDictionary` will always have int as key and `List<string>` as value. You don't need to specify this generic parameters each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you are asking, but I think you just want to create your own generic which wraps the generic `SortedDictionary`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Controller.Framework
{
   class CSortedDictionary<CustomDataType1, CustomDataType2>
   {
      private SortedDictionary<CustomDataType1, CustomDataType2> m_dictionary;

      // other methods which work on m_dictionary;
   }
}

// Create custom dictionary...
var custom_dictionary = new CSortedDictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

Or inherit as Sergey says

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Controller.Framework
{
   class CSortedDictionary<CustomDataType1, CustomDataType2>: SortedDictionary<CustomDataType1, CustomDataType2> 
   {
      // other methods which work on m_dictionary;
   }
}

// Create custom dictionary...
var custom_dictionary = new CSortedDictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

Maybe you want to consider an extension method for `SortedDictionary`, although this is frowned upon.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Controller.Framework
{
   public static class CSortedDictionaryExtensions
   {
      public static DoSomething<CustomDataType1, CustomDataType2>(this SortedDictionary<CustomDataType1, CustomDataType2> dictionary){
        dictionary.SomeMethod();
      }

      // other methods which work on m_dictionary;
   }
}

// Create custom dictionary...
var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, List<string>>();
dictionary.DoSomething();
```

[written but not compiled]